# C 'float' generating random answers

Tags: c, floating-point, division

My output should be:

```
ch = *
f = 200
ch = /
f = 0.50
```

But for some reason the "/" case is a random number every time I run the program. 1639747584 and the next I get 206200832, why is this? It's also the only portion of the program where I use 'float' instead of 'int'.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

void main() {
    char ch; 
    int f;
    int a = 10, b = 20;

    ch = '*';
    printf("ch = %c\n", ch);
    switch (ch) {
        case '*': f = a * b; printf("f = %d\n", f);
        break;
        case '/': f = a / b; printf("f = %d\n", f);
        default: printf("invalid operator\n");
    }
    ch = '/';
    printf("ch = %c\n", ch);
    (float) f;
    switch (ch) {
        case '*': f = a * b; printf("f = %d\n", f);
        case '/': f = a / b; printf("f = %d\n", f);
        break;
        default: printf("invalid operator\n");
    }
}
```

Okay, I replaced the '(float)f' line with a new variable, changed the print command, and cast (a/b) to 'float', but now I just get 0.00 as the result. What else is wrong?

Updated code:

```
    ch = '/';
    printf("ch = %c\n", ch);
    float g;
    switch (ch) {
        case '*': f = a * b; printf("f = %d\n", f);
        case '/': g = (float)(a / b); printf("f = %.2f\n", g);
        break;
        default: printf("invalid operator\n");
    }
```

Comment: So you expect the `int f` to be `0.5` ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `(float) f;` ?

Comment: You cannot change the type of `f` once it's defined. You may want to declare another float number variable for `/`, and also cast your `a / b` to float before the division, since `1/2 = 0` in `C`, also change the output to `printf("f = %f\n", float_f)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 10, b = 20;
float g = (float)(a / b);  // problem code
```

Performs an integer division of `a/b`.  The result is an `int`.  Casting that quotient to an `(float)` does not recover the fraction discarded as part of the integer division.  Insure the arguments are floating point before dividing.

```
float g = (float) a / b;
// or better
// in general, better to avoid casts to accomplish coding goals.
float g = 1.0 * a / b;
// or 
float g = a;
g /= b;
```

---

```
(float) f;
```

This line of code has no effect. It is a cast of the `int` variable `f` to a `float` value. The result of that cast is discarded and the line of code is likely optimized out resulting in no emitted executable code concerning it.

---

To save different types of data in a single object, use a `union` and keep track of the field that was last used to save data to it.

```
struct universal {
  char kind; 
  union {
    int i;
    float f;
  } u;
} y;

switch (ch) {
  case '*': 
    y.kind = 'i';
    y.u.i = a * b;
    break;
  case '/': 
    y.kind = 'f';
    y.u.f = (float) a / b;
    break;
  default:
    y.kind = 0;
}

switch (y.kind) {
  case 'f' : printf("y = %f\n", y.u.f); break; //or "%.2f" for only 2 places to right of .
  case 'i' : printf("y = %d\n", y.u.d); break;
  default  : printf("y = ?\n"
}
```